# PHP replaceChild for each parentNode

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm using this PHP code to replace a series of nodes in an XML file:

```
<?php
$xml = "
<products>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
 </product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
</products>
";
 function renameTags($xml, $old, $new)
{
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName($old);

$toRemove = array();

foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
$newNode = $dom->createElement($new);

foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute)
{
    $newNode->setAttribute($attribute->name, $attribute->value);
}

foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
{
    $newNode->appendChild($node->removeChild($child));
}

$node->parentNode->appendChild($newNode);
$toRemove[] = $node;
  break;

}

foreach ($toRemove as $node)
{
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

}

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
return $dom->saveXML();
}

$xml = renameTags($xml, 'name', 'Source');
$xml = renameTags($xml, 'name', 'parentCategory');
$xml = renameTags($xml, 'name', 'Category');
$xml = renameTags($xml, 'name', 'subCategory');
$xml = renameTags($xml, 'name', 'sisterCategory');

echo $xml;
?>
```

However, this code only replaces and only works for one product set.
I think I need to call a foreach statement somewhere in the function that consists of foreach parentNode('product') replace tag names. What do I need to add for the function to iterate over all sets of product?

The above code will print this: (notice that the first set of name nodes are gone, and are replaced by the specified new nodes)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<Source>Buy</Source>
<parentCategory>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</parentCategory>
<Category>Car Installation Parts</Category>
<subCategory>Deck Installation Parts</subCategory>
<sisterCategory>Antennas &amp; Adapters</sisterCategory></product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
<product>
<ItemId>531670</ItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<name>Buy</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</product>
</products>
```

As you can see, it only replaces one instance of product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The break in that foreach was your problem: it was stopping at the first `<name>` node it ran into, regardless of where it was in the document.

First you'd have to loop through the products, then through the the product's `<name>` nodes. Something like the following:

```
function renameTags($xml, $old, $new) {
    $toRemove = array();
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $products = $dom->getElementsByTagName('product');

    foreach($products as $product) {
        $nodes = $product->getElementsByTagName($old);

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $newNode = $dom->createElement($new);

            foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
                $newNode->setAttribute($attribute->name, $attribute->value);
            }

            foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                $newNode->appendChild($node->removeChild($child));
            }

            $node->parentNode->appendChild($newNode);
            $toRemove[] = $node;

            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($toRemove as $node) {
      $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

    $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
    return $dom->saveXML();
}
```